# How to select a value from array of elements within a dropdown array

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to select a dropdown value (Company Managed) from an array of elements. But, ending up with error

> Failed: element.all(...).get(...).click(...).element.all is not a
>   function

Could anyone help me with this issue.

Protractor/JasmineJs Snippet:

```
element.all(by.className('btn btn-default dropdown-toggle')).get(0).click().element
       .all(by.repeater('lookupData in lookupDataValues | filter: filteredValue'))
       .get(0).click();
```

Code Snippet:

```
    <button ng-disabled="customDisabled()" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" style="min-width: 0px;padding: 3px;border-radius: 0px;"
    data-toggle="dropdown" ng-click="displayDropDownForSelectingValues()">
    <span style="background:white;border-right: white; font-size:12px;" id="statusinput" class="ng-binding"></span>
    <div class="caret_container" style="display:inline-block;">
        <span class="caret" style="margin-top: 0px;"></span>
    </div>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-scroll" ng-click="preventBlur($event)" role="menu" ng-show="showList"
    style="">
    <li class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw" ng-hide="hideLoading" style="margin-left: 50%; font-size: 18px; display: none;"></li>
    <li class="searchInputBox" ng-show="hideLoading &amp;&amp; showList" style="padding: 0px 2%;">
        <input type="text" ng-keyup="updateFilter()" id="managementTypeIdSearch" role="menuitem" class="searchInput" style="width:100%;">
        <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
    </li>
    <!-- ngRepeat: lookupData in lookupDataValues | filter: filteredValue -->
    <li ng-repeat="lookupData in lookupDataValues | filter: filteredValue" class="ng-scope">
        <a ng-href="" role="menuitem" ng-click="updateValue(lookupData.key)" style="font-size:12px;" class="ng-binding">Company Managed</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat="lookupData in lookupDataValues | filter: filteredValue" class="ng-scope">
        <a ng-href="" role="menuitem" ng-click="updateValue(lookupData.key)" style="font-size:12px;" class="ng-binding">Customer Managed</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<button ng-disabled="customDisabled()" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" style="min-width: 0px;padding: 3px;border-radius: 0px;"
    data-toggle="dropdown" ng-click="displayDropDownForSelectingValues()">
    <span style="background:white;border-right: white; font-size:12px;" id="statusinput" class="ng-binding"></span>
    <div class="caret_container" style="display:inline-block;">
        <span class="caret" style="margin-top: 0px;"></span>
    </div>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-scroll" ng-click="preventBlur($event)" role="menu" ng-show="showList"
    style="">
    <li class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw" ng-hide="hideLoading" style="margin-left: 50%; font-size: 18px; display: none;"></li>
    <li class="searchInputBox" ng-show="hideLoading &amp;&amp; showList" style="padding: 0px 2%;">
        <input type="text" ng-keyup="updateFilter()" id="resiliencyIdSearch" role="menuitem" class="searchInput" style="width:100%;">
        <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
    </li>
    <!-- ngRepeat: lookupData in lookupDataValues | filter: filteredValue -->
    <li ng-repeat="lookupData in lookupDataValues | filter: filteredValue" class="ng-scope">
        <a ng-href="" role="menuitem" ng-click="updateValue(lookupData.key)" style="font-size:12px;" class="ng-binding">--Please Select--</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat="lookupData in lookupDataValues | filter: filteredValue" class="ng-scope">
        <a ng-href="" role="menuitem" ng-click="updateValue(lookupData.key)" style="font-size:12px;" class="ng-binding">Backup</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat="lookupData in lookupDataValues | filter: filteredValue" class="ng-scope">
        <a ng-href="" role="menuitem" ng-click="updateValue(lookupData.key)" style="font-size:12px;" class="ng-binding">Secure</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat="lookupData in lookupDataValues | filter: filteredValue" class="ng-scope">
        <a ng-href="" role="menuitem" ng-click="updateValue(lookupData.key)" style="font-size:12px;" class="ng-binding">Secure+</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat="lookupData in lookupDataValues | filter: filteredValue" class="ng-scope">
        <a ng-href="" role="menuitem" ng-click="updateValue(lookupData.key)" style="font-size:12px;" class="ng-binding">Standard</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Error:

> ```
> Message:
>   Failed: element.all(...).get(...).click(...).element.all is not a function
> Stack:
>   TypeError: element.all(...).get(...).click(...).element.all is not a function
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate the two `element.all` calls by a semicolon (;).

```
element.all(by.className('btn btn-default dropdown-toggle')).get(0).click();
element.all(by.repeater('lookupData in lookupDataValues | filter: filteredValue'))
       .get(0).click();
```

Comment: Tried and ended up with error : Message:
  Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: @Ashish Then it depends on your testing code, which you don't show.

Comment: This indeed worked after some trail and error method. Thanks !